# Existence of a faithfully flat algebra with a cancellation property

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme (or even algebraic stack). Let's assume that it is nice enough, for example noetherian.

> Is there a (faithfully flat) $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ with the following properties?
>
> 1. $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{A})$ is affine (as a scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$).
> 2. If $M \in \mathsf{Qcoh}(X)$ has the property that $\hom(N \otimes \mathcal{A},M)=0$ for all $N \in \mathsf{Qcoh}(X)$, then $M=0$.

Note that  1. is easy to arrange. If $p : P \to X$ is any fpqc covering with $P$ affine, then $p_* \mathcal{O}_P$ does. But 2. doesn't hold for every $\mathcal{A}$. If $X$ is affine, we can of course take $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{O}_X$. I expect that $\mathcal{A}$ also exists when $X$ is Adams (i.e. $X$ has enough vector bundles).

Background: I can prove that 2. implies that the "cocomplete $\otimes$-ideal" (suitably defined by closure under tensor products, colimits, quotients, and transfinite "right extensions") generated by $\mathcal{A}$ is $\mathsf{Qcoh}(X)$. By usual descent theory this wouldn't be surprising when we use use kernels, but here only cokernels and alike are used. The existence of $\mathcal{A}$ would solve $\approx 3$ open problems in my thesis.

Comment: What is a counterexample to 2?

Comment: @Will: $X=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$, $A=\mathbb{Z}[1/2] \times \mathbb{Z}[1/3]$, $M=\mathbb{Z}$.